# How to create this loft between 2 individually defined group of edges and a bezier curve

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

What would be the most efficient way to copy the outline of the 2 edge based objects shown so that i can apply them as bevel objects along this Bezier curve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If those are two different meshes, then there are a tons of ways to connect them-- and that's the problem.  Before you can contemplate doing this, you need to think about what way you want vertices on one mesh to correspond to vertices on the other mesh.

Comment: As a starting point maybe just connecting each vertices one to one as the meshes are duplicates..

Comment: If they're the same mesh, in different objects, it's easy, trivial.  Convert the mesh to a curve (if necessary) and then designate it as a bevel object for the bezier curve.  Adjust bevier curve tilt (on a per-control basis, select curve control in edit and ctrl t move mouse confirm) to match what you want.

Comment: A link to a file would allow me to give a better answer, with pics and instructions using your exact geometry.

Comment: Ok! I will add models to this post tomorrow!! Thanks Nathan!

Comment: @Nathan: I have uploaded the model. I consist of 2 different curves/mesh. I suspect there  will be difficulty lofting because of the different number of vertices in each?

Comment: If there's a different number of vertices in each, it is not the same mesh at start and beginning.  Again, in that case, it's necessary to establish how each end's vertices corresponds to the other end's vertices.

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip. Crucial points is the same number of vertices etc.